# Unable to serialize an object and getting it back in Android

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to serlize an Enum Class so I can restore in in onCreate() method so each run I have an updated class.

Here is the code for serlizing and deserializing the class:

```
private void serializeModulesManager() {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("modules.ser",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        out.writeObject(Module.values());
        out.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void restoreModulesManager() {
    FileInputStream fileIn;
    Module[] arr = null;
    try {

        fileIn = openFileInput("modules.ser");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        arr = (Module[]) in.readObject();

        for (Module c : arr) {
            Module.valueOf(c.name()).serilize(c);
        }

        in.close();
        fileIn.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I call serializeModulesManager() in onDestroy() , and I call restoreModulesManager() in onCreate()..

The problem is that when I force close (from task manager), ObjectInputStream fails to read the object and I get an "EOFException"..

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you absolutley need to use a file for this? I know if you go into your Module Object class and add `implements Parcelable` you can use a Parcel object to save the data and use a Parceleable CREATOR to restore it. And just use the `savedState Bundle` to store the `Module []` as a `ParcelablArray`

Comment: The way you are doing it you should use a while loop instead of a for loop and say `while(in.isAvailable() > 0){arr = (Module[]) in.readObject(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i would handle this. This is a simple object with only a title field but you can use this same idea for more complicated objects

```
public class MyObject implements Parcelable{

public String title;


public MyObject(){}


public MyObject(Parcel source){
    title = source.readString();

}


public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return this.title;
}

    // Parcel Overrides
@Override
public int describeContents(){return 0;}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags){

    dest.writeString(title);
}

// Parcelable Creator

public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyObject> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyObject>(){
    @Override
    public MyObject createFromParcel(Parcel source){
        return new MyObject(source);

    }

    @Override
    public MyObject [] newArray(int size){
        return new MyObject[size];
    }   
}
}
```

And then in your class that instantiates the object

```
 // Add this in onSavedInstanceState(Bundle outState)

 outState.putParcelableArray("MyObjectArray",myObjects);
```

then in OnCreate or whichever method your using to restore UI

```
 // Add this

 myObjects = (MyObject [])savedInstanceState.getParcelableArray("MyObjectArray");
```